# IdentityResources.Profile required for implicit and hybrid flow?

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver4

Fiddling around with the [quickstart examples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts) from IdentityServer4 and reading the docs I came across this statement from [this page](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/resources.html)(emphasis mine):

> The OpenID Connect specification specifies a couple of standard
>   identity resources. **The minimum requirement is, that you provide
>   support for emitting a unique ID for your users - also called the
>   subject id. This is done by exposing the standard identity resource
>   called openid**

Using *Quickstart3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication*-Solution for example I thought I just try to omit (in Project *QuickstartIdentityServer* - file *Config.cs*)

```
IdentityResources.Profile()
```

from `Config.GetIdentityResources` and

```
IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile
```

from the MVC-Client's `AllowedScopes`

But when I try to call the Secure-View I get this error:

> Sorry, there was an error : **invalid_scope**

So my question is, are actually both `Profile` and `OpenId` required, did I forget to change something else to make it work or have I just misunderstood the cited statement?

Answer (score 3):

I will answer this based on [openid specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html).

The spec mentioned following about the **`scope`**,

> REQUIRED. OpenID Connect requests MUST contain the openid scope value. If the openid scope value is not present, the behavior is entirely unspecified. Other scope values MAY be present. Scope values used that are not understood by an implementation SHOULD be ignored. See Sections 5.4 and 11 for additional scope values defined by this specification.

You should never remove **`IdentityResources.OpenId()`** in your scope configurations.

Furthermore flowing is there about **`profile`** scope,

> OPTIONAL. This scope value requests access to the End-User's default profile Claims, which are: name, family_name, given_name, middle_name, nickname, preferred_username, profile, picture, website, gender, birthdate, zoneinfo, locale, and updated_at.

Though profile is optional, I believe this example([ImplicitFlowAuthentication](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/release/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication)) need to have profile scope to function correctly. Thus giving this error.